# Cannot get storage account key. Cannot read property 'slice' of null in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

When i am trying to create any linked service in azure data factory then i am getting the error message.
"Cannot get storage account key. Cannot read property 'slice' of null"

Request you to please help resolve

Comment: I don't know Azure Data Factory but this sounds like you're passing null to a JavaScript function that's expecting an array.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs more details.

I can only tell about how the linked service can create success.

It seems you want to create a linked service for azure storage account, so just follow the below steps:

2, Go to the manage tab and create a new linked service:

[image]

2, choose a type of linked service.

3, give the linked service your storage key, it is getting from this place:

[image]

4, then you can create the linked service success:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help